# Unable to import Project/dependencies.scala using effective SBT

Tags: scala, sbt

I have many modules in the same project such that the structure is somethign along the lines of:

```
Root
- ProjA
- ProbB
- ProjC
build.sbt
```

I had a build.sbt with all of the details in at the root of the project, it was clunky and we encountered problems when I needed to give someone ProjB.

I then found a post and slides on Effective SBT and thought it sounded like a great solution.  Implementation has not bee painless though.

I'm updating the structure to look like:

```
Root
- ProjA
--build.props
--dependencies.scala
-ProjA
--build.props
--dependencies.scala
build.sbt
```

example of Dependencies:

```
object Dependencies {

  //specific versions (if required) use '% name-version' to add to the dependency

  //libraries
  val scalaTest       = "org.scalatest" % "scalatest_2.10" % "2.2.6"
  val slf4j           = "org.slf4j" % "slf4j-log4j12" % "1.7.13"
  val akkaActor       = "com.typesafe.akka" % "akka-actor_2.10" % "2.3.14"
  val akkaTest        = "com.typesafe.akka" % "akka-testkit_2.10" % "2.3.14"
  val awsCloudwatch   = "com.amazonaws" % "aws-java-sdk-cloudwatch" % 

"1.10.28"
  val cloudwatchDependencies = Seq(awsCloudwatch, akkaActor, akkaTest)
```

I'm then trying to use this in my build.sbt but it won't allow me to import the file

in build.sbt I have:

```
  lazy val cloudwatch = (project in file("cloudwatch")).
  settings(commonSettings: _*).
  settings(
name := "Cloudwatch",
libraryDependencies += cloudwatchDependencies
```

)

but I'm unable to import or pick up the dependencies.  Is there something obviously wrong that I'm missing?  Is it the correct/wrong approach?

Thanks for any help / advice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The configuration objects need to reside at a special place: `/project`.
If you move them there everything should be fine.

see: http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13.5/docs/Getting-Started/Multi-Project.html#common-code

If you want to have a per project configuration, it is possible to have a separate `build.sbt` for each project. This approach bears the additional gain that it is the idiomatic way to approach this problem.

The setup could look like this:

```
root
-build.sbt
-cloudwatch.sbt
- ProjA
--build.sbt
-ProjB
--build.sbt
```

If you still need more granularity, it would be possible to have several `*.sbt` files, which will all be included in the `build.sbt`

```
root
-build.sbt
- ProjA
--build.sbt
-ProjB
--build.sbt
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for taking the time to reply.  When you say special place... in IntelliJ i have a "project[projName-build](sources root)" with a blue scala icon next to it, is that where you mean

Comment: you're beautiful, thanks!  Just popped it in there and voila!  all the red squiggles went! thanks again!!! :D